# Solr Conditional Highlighting: How to highlight with conditions?

Tags: solr, conditional-statements, highlight

In a Solr Implementation, I am trying to do some conditional highlight depending on others fields than the one we search on.

I want to get the matching result a field "content" highlighted only if it is indicated in Solr that this field can be exposed for this element.

Given a Solr base populated with :

```
[{ firstname:"Roman",
 content: "A quick response is the best",
access:"" },
{ "firstname":"Roman",
 "content": "Responsive is important",
"access":"contentAuthorized" }
]
```

I would like to get both document in my answer, and the highlight on the "content" field only for the one with the data "access":"contentAuthorized", so I am executing the query:

```
q:(firstname:r* OR (+tags:contentAuthorized AND +content:r*))
```

The expected answer would be:

```
...
{
      {
        "firstname":"Roman"
      },
      {
        "firstname":"Roman"
      }
},
highlighting":{
    "0f278cb5-7150-42f9-8dca-81bfa68a9c6e":{
      "firstname":["<em>Roman</em>"],
    "105c6464-0350-4873-9936-b46c39c88647":{
      "firstname":["<em>Roman</em>"],
      "content":["<em>Responsive</em> is important],
      }
}
```

But I actually get:

```
...
{
      {
        "firstname":"Roman"
      },
      {
        "firstname":"Roman"
      }
},
highlighting":{
    "0f278cb5-7150-42f9-8dca-81bfa68a9c6e":{
      "firstname":["<em>Roman</em>"],
      "content":["A quick <em>response</em> is the best"],
    "105c6464-0350-4873-9936-b46c39c88647":{
      "firstname":["<em>Roman</em>"],
      "content":["<em>Responsive</em> is important],
      }
}
```

So, I get the "content" on the highlight of the second element while (+tags:contentAuthorized AND +content:r*) is false.

Does anyone have an idea of how I could do conditional highlighting with Solr so ?
Thank you for reading this and for taking your time to think about it :D

Comment: I don't think Solr supports the extra logic for highlighting that you are looking for. I think you'll need to implement the additional logic in your client application. Another thing you could do is look at the configuration of the "solr.HighlightComponent" searchComponent in you solr_config.xml.

Comment: Thank you for the answer @HectorCorrea, adding the logic on the client application is the easiest solution I think, you are right.
There is some cons: it means we would need an application's server which is stronger to make those operations on the Json returned by Solr, and we would loose the Solr's speed (like, if we try to do it on 50 000 returned documents). But, overall, the solution is quite great :D. I don't know how to make the best of the "solr.HighlightComponent" features yet, I didn't see anything which could help to to do that, but thank you for the complete list. Wish you the best

Answer (score 0):

If you want highlighting to be applied on certain fields only, then you need to set the query parameter `hl.fl` to those fields. In your case `hl.fl=content`. You should then set `hl.requireFieldMatch=true`.

Refer to Solr Highlighting documentation:

> By default, false, all query terms will be highlighted for each field to be highlighted (hl.fl) no matter what fields the parsed query refer to. If set to true, only query terms aligning with the field being highlighted will in turn be highlighted.

For further info on how to use the query parameters: https://solr.apache.org/guide/8_6/highlighting.html